# cascading combobox with this simplest example

Tags: javascript, jquery

from serverside I'm returning data in following structure
 results.houses 
 where each house and `Id` and `Name` and Doors collection. 
 Each `Door` has `Id` and `Name`.

```
 $.each(results.houses, function (index, value) {
    $('#HouseId').append('<option value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Name + '</option>');   
    var selectedHouse = results.SelectedHouse[0].Id;  

    $('#HouseId').val(selectedHouse);
    $('#HouseId').combobox('refresh');
 }
```

How can I populate Doors combobox with `#DoorId` 
if I already know selected house from above variable `selectedHouse`.

**Update:**

json data is returned in following format from the server side controller

```
var _houses = HousesRepository.All().Select(x => new
{
    Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name,
    Doors = x.Doors.Select(a => new { Id = a.Id, Name = a.Name, IsDefault = a.IsDefault })
});

var data = new 
{
    selectedHouse = new[] { new { Id = 1, Name = "House 100 "} },
    houses = _houses    
}    
return Json(data);
```

Comment: `Doors combobox` where is the data for this?

Comment: provide a link to the combobox library

Comment: @MoshFeu you can presume that inside each value.Doors has collection of for each house with Id and Name property.

Comment: @madalinivascu please ignore combobox library for now. It's bootstrap.

Comment: @user1765862 can you show us the JSON of an example house?

Comment: @MoshFeu question is update with json representation

Comment: Please give us the **JSON**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a selected tag to the selected element:

```
 $('#HouseId').find('option[value="'+selectedHouse+'"]').prop('selected',true);
```

or better

```
var selectedHouse = results.SelectedHouse[0].Id;  
var selected ='';
if(value.Id == selectedHouse) {
 selected = "selected"
}
$('#HouseId').append('<option '+selected+' value="' + value.Id + '">' + value.Name + '</option>');
$('#HouseId').combobox('refresh');
```

Comment: and how to load corresponding doors into combobox upon selected House. That collection is available trough value.Doors where each door has Id and Name

Comment: @user1765862 do another loop for the doors

Comment: can you provide example, loading doors collection only for selected house.

Comment: @user1765862 if you give me the json i will , i don't know you json structure

Comment: @user1765862 i don't see any VALID Json in your question, accept this answer and post another question